# How to make this relay system act like a latch?

Tags: microcontroller, relay

I want to use the following external-interlock schema to control a relay when the interlock terminal is opened or shorted.

The micro-controller does many other things but I restricted the pin-outs to focus on the relay part.

The K1 relay is a non-latching normally open relay. The 5V supply supplies voltage to external interlock control and to the micro-controller as well as to the relay coil. R7 and R8 are there to limit the LED current. R11 and C5 is to prevent bouncing. D1 input detects the interlock ON/OFF state, D2 output goes ON and activates the relay so the 12V power supply turns off. Once the interlock terminals shorted the relay will close contacts and the 12V supply will be ON.

[image]

My problem is that I want to make use of another switch (or push button ect) call it SW_New which is coupled to the micro-controller so that the relay acts like a latch. When someone opens the interlock the relay will activate but it will not close again when the interlock is shorted; instead it will require SW_New to be pushed again. I’m a bit confused how I could implement it. What sort of logic or switch/button would be work for such aim?

edit for an answer:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to implement the new logic in the uC code (connecting SW_New to a uC pin), or with external logic circuit/devices?

Comment: uC code is fine. Not even the C code(I can write myself) I need to know what to do.

Comment: If possible with uC solution and a adhoc component(like a special switch or button ect) better for me.

Answer (score 2):

> What sort of logic or switch/button would be work for such aim?

Any switch, since the latch function will be achieved through software.

If the MCU and relay coil both uses 5V and the MCU pin can source sufficient current, you may be able to drive the relay straight from the MCU. Otherwise use a NPN BJT or some other driver circuit in between. Similarly, if the relay coil needs 12V or 24V (the most common ones), you can solve this too with a circuit in between.

No matter how you drive the coil, you must absolutely use a flyback diode across it. I see none in your schematic.

Don't place the LED in series with the switch. Place it after the switch together with its series resistor and the cathode towards ground. Because there's no apparent need to sink the LED current through the MCU and also you don't want the LED voltage drop to muck up your debouncing and/or button reads. Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6QwKr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 = Regulate LED current
R2 = Protect MCU
R3 = Signal pull-down

As for how to write the software:

- Periodically poll and debounce the switch. For example in a cyclic timer interrupt hitting every 5ms or 10ms. You *can* use hardware debouncing with a RC filter too but why, since you have a MCU available.
- Store the state of the button in a variable. Change the state of the variable when the de-bounced button value either goes from low to high (soon as button is pressed) or from high to low (when the button was pressed and released).
- If you need the state of the relay to persist after MCU reset / power off, then you will need to store the button state in on-chip data flash/eeprom, so if that's a requirement then pick a suitable MCU with data flash.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
The relay module takes care of the flyback diode and built in transistors ect.
I think I understand what you mean by keeping the state updated by the push button.
So I just need an extra push button which also gotta be debounced as well.

But I didnt get the series LED part. Could you show me what you mean by wiring the LED proper way?
Is it possible to use for you the built in tool for drawing diagram? More clear than sentences sometimes.

Comment: "Don't place the LED in series with the switch." When you say switch here do you mean the interlock in my diagram or the switch to be added?

Comment: @cm64 It's very basic electronics but I added a schematic.

Comment: I see just wanted to be sure SW1 in your diagram is Interlock terminal in my question correct?

Comment: We also talked about reset push button I wanted to be sure what you mean by the SW1

Comment: @cm64 Nobody has talked about a reset button, at least not I.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler solution.

[image]

The 12 V relay K1 is energised by the 12 V supply and switches on the + 12 V line.

When the external interlock opens, the relay is de-energised.

The relay is re-energised when the external interlock closes and the restart push button is actuated.

If required the relay contact may be taken as an input to the micro-controller.

The following version has been created to suit your requirements.

[image]

The 5 V relay, that switches on the 12 V SMPS, is to be selected from 'high in-rush current' models to avoid contact welding. More details at [230V AC Relay won't switch off](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/614872/230v-ac-relay-wont-switch-off/615079#615079) and [Switch stuck in closed position](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/618542/switch-stuck-in-closed-position/618551#618551).

It is energised when the external interlock is closed and the 'restart' push button is actuated.

It is de-energised when the external interlock opens.

Comment: But my relay can only be powered by +5Vdc not 12Vdc. And my relay is DC controlled AC relay. See my diagram its contacts are on the Line. Please reconsider your answer.

Comment: My post has been edited to suit your requirements, though it is not standard practice to switch the mains input to the SMPS. You would need to select the 5V relay from 'high-inrush current' models to avoid contact welding.

Comment: I will use this relay modue https://download.mikroe.com/documents/add-on-boards/click/relay/relay-click-schematic-v100-a.pdf which uses this relay https://docs.rs-online.com/356b/0900766b80660fe5.pdf In the schematic there are V1 V2 are they thermistor? Can this module handle inrush currents?

Comment: G6D relays are not TV rated. G4W relays are.

Comment: I see maybe thats why they added MOV or thermistor in the module. Btw in your schematic there is two K1 contacts. One is DC one is AC. Its like the relay u use have single coil two switch. Thats not type of relay in question.

Comment: Yes, it's an MOV across the relay contact. The MOV across a contact in an AC circuit is akin to a flyback diode in a DC circuit. The switch-on surge current in a power supply is  the high initial capacitor charging current. Relays are also available with e.g. DPDT, 3PDT contacts etc.

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea for the module I have. I will make sketch and hope to hear your opnion.

Comment: What do you think about this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppeGD.png I tried to use your idea for the module I have. X is the common node.

Comment: You may shout 'Eureka' and go ahead! Do hope that the contact does not weld when the mains to the SMPS is switched.

Comment: How about using the relay module I have at 12V 5/6A for the DC line? Its at the limit but at least there's no inrush current issue. Its rated for 30VDC 5A. In my case 12V and current will be around 5A or a bit more.

Comment: That should be okay. You may go ahead and use it.  You need to have flyback diodes for inductive loads.